# In-site Hash tag/Search anchor

Tags: javascript, hashtag

Please this is my first time asking.Please i want to know how to make an in-site hash tag or just a tag. For example when you click on the **Javascript** tagged with this Question you get all related Questions.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you are asking... Could you be more specific?

Comment: What i Want is to make something (like a BB code) that will get related results to a given tag

Comment: Are you talking about a website you are writing or are you talking about Tags on StackOverflow?  If you are talking about a website, please show us some code and an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Altoyr. Am talking about a site am building. I want to show related post/article just like Stackoverflow,if its possible. But i havn't tried any code yet.

Comment: StackOverflow is a big website and it seema to me,  that you are not very experienced. You should start coding with some easier goals.